# Different Arrow in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode

Is there any list of all possible arrows that I can write with LaTeX?
For example like this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_(symbol)

Comment: go through this link http://garsia.math.yorku.ca/MPWP/LATEXmath/node9.html

Comment: Some arrows are missing. For example, I was reading a paper and i found this one: 

http://i67.tinypic.com/15hjtah.gif

How can I do an arrow like this?

Comment: Do you need other arrows than in the link? If necessary, you can create them yourself. Simplest way is using inkscape, inlude it as pdf or eps and scale it to the fontsize.

Comment: http://www.latex-pfeile.de/ Does this help?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I'd like to upvote your comment, but I don't have enough privileges.

Comment: I posted it as an answer. So you can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good overview on [latex-pfeile.de/](http://www.latex-pfeile.de/). It is German, but it should be pretty much self explaining.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best source for finding arrows and other symbols is `The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List`: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive

Answer (score 2):

The arrow you provide a link in a comment is `\rightsquigarrow`, defined in `amssymb`. In my opinion this family is nicer (and more complete) in `mathabx`, and you can use some of its characters, while still loading amssymb:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}

\usepackage{graphicx}
    \DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
    \DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
  <-6> mathb5 <6-7> mathb6 <7-8> mathb7
  <8-9> mathb8 <9-10> mathb9
  <10-12> mathb10 <12-> mathb12
    }{}
    \DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\varleftsquigarrow}{\mathrel}{mathb}{"F8}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\varrightsquigarrow}{\mathrel}{mathb}{"F9}
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\varleftrightsquigarrow}{\mathrel}{mathb}{"FA}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{array}{lccc}
  \texttt{amssymb: } &   & \rightsquigarrow & \leftrightsquigarrow \\
  \texttt{mathabx: } & \varleftsquigarrow & \varrightsquigarrow & \varleftrightsquigarrow 
  \end{array} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]